# Invalid string format for Date

Tags: c#, string, api, date

I have values ​​sent to API by HTML.

```
<input name="EndDate" type="text" value="" id="EndDate" class="date" autocomplete="Off">
```

js side :

```
 var dropDate = $("#EndDate").val() + " " + $("#DropTime").val();
```

Sometimes the API returns different results. Ex: **'j22.08.2022 09:00'** or **'21.08.2022. 09:00'**

I want to edit the wrong data on the API side. Is it possible to do this with a regex or mask operation?

Comment: Why aren't you using `<input type="date">` ?

Comment: @Dai i know,because I am having trouble getting value with date format. It works fine as text, only in rare cases it returns an invalid string